# Is this "contest" question on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401930/most-efficient-way-to-conduct-a-series-of-dataframe-manipulations) ([image for <10kers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UqH1.png)) is structured as a contest where the user will award a bounty to the best answer. If all the description of the contest, bounty award etc were removed it looks a bit like a "write this code for me" request.

Is this question off topic? Or should it be edited?

Comment: Should be on PCG instead.  There's no actual question being asked.  It's waaaay too broad.

Comment: It should rather go to SE Code Review, as long the code is already woring as intended. It just appears _too broad_ for the intended format of Stack Overflow.

Comment: How did you make that uber long screenshot? Take a bunch and stich with a needle and thread?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I was actually thinking the same thing! However, an important note: If that question had actually been posted on PPCG, it would probably be closed for lack of a winning criteria. (I would have VTC'ed) From a quick glance, It seems dangerously close to a [popularity-contest](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) which was once on topic but are now frowned upon.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Popularity contests are still on-topic on PPCG.

Comment: @dorukayhan yes, but it is really hard to do a popularity contest correctly, and lots of bad challenges use "popularity contest" as an excuse to not have a good scoring method. That's why I said "frowned upon" not "off-topic"

Answer (score 21):

I like the spirit of the question, but that aside, from a purely content oriented view, this question is off topic.

It is essentially a story, paired with a promise of a bounty (which is generally frowned upon), and a list of requirements. It is very close to on topic though. It is clearly written by someone who enjoys coding. It is related to programming.

However, what it lacks is the large issue with the question. It lacks a clear problem. Instead it provides a place to riff off of an existing code example. The help center states

> Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

And that is essentially the main issue with this question, there is no clear problem statement, just a list of requirements and an example of how to actually solve that list.

Furthermore, open-ended questions are also discouraged

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

In the end, this question boils down to being too subjective. While there are arguments to be made for including or not including these, as of now they are not allowed. This topic is covered extensively [by Robert Cartaino](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and [by Jeff Atwood](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

As a result, it is too broad.

Comment: If there was a clear problem statement, would you still say that a question like this was too open-ended? It seems to me that its open-endedness is a function of the primary problem (lack of a clear problem statement), rather than a separate problem.

Comment: Open endedness certainly is a function of not having a clear problem statement. If there were a clearer problem statement it very well could be on topic.

Answer (score 5):

*I might be wrong with the historical info on this post. Correct me if that's the case.*

---

## No

Programming challenges were deemed off-topic on Stack Overflow **and** Software Engineering like five years ago when [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)<sup>1</sup> went into public beta. Even if such a question is on-topic thanks to a loophole in SO's scope, it would be closed as too broad since programming challenges are essentially "plz send teh codez (and screw teh coding conventionz)" questions.

<sup>1 - The site is more focused on code golf, but other kinds of challenges are accepted as well. [There's even a tag for challenges like the one mentioned in this question!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)</sup>

Comment: The kind of puzzles that were deemed off-topic are the ones that do not involve practical programming problems. As it says in the Stack Overflow help page, describing the site's scope. Puzzles and code golf is fun to certain people, but it is far from practical. If you ever tried to write actual code like that, you'd be hanged at high noon.

Comment: @CodyGray As a PPCG user, and as I'm sure other PPCG users will tell you, we do have "practical" competitions -- fastest-code, especially

Comment: Hmm yeah, you found one of many contests that is practical. It's going to have to do a lot of good to make up for the code golf tag. But that wasn't *really* the point of my comment. Rather, any time you have a practical programming question that is reasonably scoped, it is on topic for Stack Overflow. Optimization questions are certainly valid here, too. It is the asker's choice which site she prefers.

Comment: @CodyGray The point is that not all questions on PPCG are Code Golf. Hence the name, *Programming Puzzles and* Code Golf. The question we're discussing is being run as a competition, aimed at "having fun", so it seems like the user would probably enjoy PPCG, and could still learn useful tricks, if they defined the challenge right. To fit well on SO, it would need to be phrased rather differently, with less emphasis on the competition and fun.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the OP for this question.  I have several motivations for asking this question, but here are some of my justifications.

## What is on topic?

Per the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

The question actually being asked is for a fast way to complete the task.  It is practical as it does many things commonly asked.  It's answerable as I've answered it. And its very specific.

It satisfies the specified conditions.  The question is whether it is congruent with your sensibilities?

## So what is the benefit that I'm proposing this has?

I have experienced some of the most insightful answers when there have been motivations to answer.  Some brilliant questions don't get answered and don't get voted on because answerers (myself included) don't have the time to answer it when there are other questions that can get me points quicker.  I'm hoping to find a way to push that motivation factor.

As a case in point, @AndyHayden voted to close the question but also provided insight on using cython.  I wouldn't have known that and already I've learned from this question.  I expect some of the brilliant posters I see answering questions might impart some wisdom that I'll find invaluable and maybe others will to.

This is a question / answer site and there is even a [Socratic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4129/socratic) badge.  Why would it have been named Socratic?  Because Socrates didn't know things?  No, Socrates taught by asking questions.  In this case, I'm seeking to learn how others might attack this problem as well as providing the means for others to share in that insight.

I anticipated some push back and I'm happy to accept whatever the community judgement is.  But I'd urge everyone to watch and see if this plays out well.

## Another question to ponder

If the question being asked was completely on-topic without question.  Would everyone feel differently?  If you'd feel the same about the the framework of the competition and promises of bounties, then it isn't the question that is the problem, its the competition and bounty manipulation.

I spoke of several motivations above.  Pushing this boundary and observing the reaction was one of them.  I'm willing and able to be perfectly respectful of everyone's opinion, but I'd like to be able to narrow in on what it is specifically we have a problem with.  I expect that some are uncomfortable with the concept of using the bounty system for competition.

Comment: I think it would do better at Code Golf, as subjective programming content is more encouraged there.

Comment: Would someone post a screenshot please? Either you or @TravisJ, since I can't see the deleted.

Comment: @Laurel (and others <10k) [here you go](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0UqH1.png)